# How to add username via PowerShell snippet in VS Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am working to convert my PowerShell_ISE profile functions into snippets in VS Code.  Part of that code is to add a header to the script. I am looking to grab the user's name from active directory and place it in a comment within the header.  Our login IDs are randomly generated.  So I am hoping to do something like this:

`#(Get-AdUser $Env:username -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName`

The problem is that the snippet inserts the code rather than the value.  I did discover that in VS Code you access the Environmental variables a little different, so I tried this.

`#(Get-AdUser ${env:username} -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName`

But that produces the output of:
`# (Get-AdUser username -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName`

Can anyone help me figure this out?

I need it to pull the env:username variable, then use that to query Active Directory for the user Display Name.

Comment: do you need to escape the `$` with `\\$`?

Comment: I think you are presuming that VS Code snippets can execute some command (PowerShell, at that) and insert the output. A quick review of the [snippets page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) suggests that that's not how snippets work. It is likely you would need to write an extension to do that.

Comment: I am returning back to this topic.  When PowerShell_ISE has a snippet you can include a function in that snippet to query either the local variables or even active directory.  When the snippet inserts text into the ISE that text includes the values from an AD query successfully.

VSCode on the other hand seems to ignore the processing of that and goes straight to a literal text insertion that includes the code used to query AD.  No amount of escape charater seems to be able to get the snippet to make a call to AD.